# What don't I understand with regular expression on Linux?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

Im using Linux mint and trying to pattern match with the `grep` command. I have read through some tutorials and they stated matching a telephone number of simply 3 digits followed by a hyphen followed by 4 digits i.e. 123-4567 matches the pattern

```
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

Okay so I understand what that regex is saying but the problem is it doesn't work at all. I have found the solution is actually

```
[0-9\]{3\}-[0-9\]{4\}
```

Now I am really confused. I thought that backslash (\) was an escape character and there is nothing there I want to escape. This second pattern works, and I have no idea why. The one I was taught in my class and find on many tutorials does not work at all. Please someone help me understand what the deal is here.

Comment: It must be that `]` and `}` have some kind of semantic meaning in Linux of their own.  Hence, you need to escape them once to make sure they make it into the regex.

Comment: Don't forget to add `^` and `$` [`^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/4LbfXv/1).

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that traditionally grep implements POSIX Basic regular expressions (BRE) and not Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). The difference is a matter of metacharacters. In BRE only `^ $ . [ ] *` are meta, all others are considered literals. ERE adds metacharacters `( ) { } ? + |` and their associated functions. Since grep without any additional options uses BRE, you actually have to add a backlash to `( ) { }` for them be considered meta characters. This is completely backwards from ERE where appending the backlash causes in to be treated as a literal. Alternatively, you can run grep with the `-E` option for it to use Extended Regular expressions or the `egrep` command. To make this a little less wordy and clear...

```
grep [0-9\]{3\}-[0-9\]{4\}
```

produces the same result as

```
grep -E [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

which produces the same result as

```
egrep [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very briefly,

`grep` uses by default standard POSIX regex in which you need to escape a couple of characters like `{`, `}` , `|`, `+`, `?`,`(`,`)` . Note that `[`, `]` are not required to be escaped!!

As escaping all of those characters is a pain you can use extended regex with grep using `grep -E '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'` or perl regex using `grep -P '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'`. Extended regex allow the use of classes of `[[:alnum:]]` for alphanum, etc. Perl regex are way more powerful since they allow lookbehind and lookahead as well as many other defined keywords.

```
$ echo '123-4567' | grep '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
>>> NO OUTPUT as the regex would match 1 digit followed literally  by {3}-  followed by literally  by 1 digit and {4}
$ echo '123-4567' | grep '[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}'
123-4567
$ echo '123-4567' | grep -P '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
123-4567
$ echo '123-4567' | grep -E '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
123-4567
```

READINGS:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html
- https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html
- http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Thank you, I actually just found an awesome Linux Command Line book hidden on my shelf and the regular expression chapter immediately stated this. I'm glad I now have confirmation though, and your answer was a bit less cryptic. Thanks a bunch, I could not find this information online no matter what I searched.